# Will it sink under circumstances?

Tags: water, buoyancy, fluid-statics

I'm a 10 year old with a question. If you have a waterproof box the shape of a prism with an open top and you have a lid that fits perfectly in the top and you fill the box with water then put the lid on top, will the lid float or sink?

Answer (score 1):

The lid will float.  The shape of the box does not matter. If the lid has a true perfect fit water will not be able to move from under the lid. so as long as the lid is placed in straight and level it will float.

Answer (score 1):

First, please avoid spamming comments, this will not help at all to increase your response rate.

Secondly, Leon's answer is not completely accurate.

For floating bodies, you have 3 options.

1. The object is more dense than the liquid -> It sinks (to the bottom)
2. The object is less dense than the liquid -> It floats
3. The object has the same density than the liquit -> It can be at equilibrium at any point in the liquid.

Now this is true regardless of the geometry of object, but you didn't specify if the box is more dense than the liquid, so a straigth answer cannot be given.

As Leon mentioned the lid will float or sink on its own, the box/water are not necessary for the analysis

A final note on geometry.
You may notice that ships do float in water, becase even though Iron is much heavier (more dense) than water, the "composite" iron-air is less dense, similarly you may observe a plate of a material which would normally sink in water float. This is because the plate sinks a little, and there is a thin layer of air just above it thanks to the [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), and the plate just barely floats.

Regards